# Generating a .h file using MIDL compiler in CMAKE

Tags: cmake, idl, midl

I have tree.idl file and generated a tree_map.h using MIDL compiler in **CMAKE**

getting this error
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(2988)
: error C2338: 'CAtlExeModuleT' must be used with neither _WINDLL nor _USRDLL defined

I have not added the defination of _WINDLL in my CMakeList.txt

Comment: Have you tried to search? E.g. [thas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878906/invoke-midl-compiler-from-cmake) describes possible way for use MIDL compiler with CMake.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through this but since I have never used MIDL before can you please tell me what this line does set(MIDL_OUTPUT

Comment: This line is a part of **multiline** command invocation. The end line of this command invocation contains `)` symbol. If you don't know what particular command means, see [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-commands.7.html).

Comment: Oks. But want to confirm what this command does. it generates the output files IFace.h, GUIDS.c, Proxy.c, ProxyDll.c   set(MIDL_OUTPUT
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/IFace.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GUIDS.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Proxy.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ProxyDll.c
)

Comment: Yes, custom command generates what is specified in its `OUTPUT` parameter. In the given case it is list of files specified in `MIDL_OUTPUT`.

Comment: can u please tell what this line COMMAND midl /h IFace.h /iid GUIDS.c /proxy Proxy.c /dlldata ProxyDll.c ${MIDL_FILE} does in add_custom_command?

Comment: `COMMAND` denotes command line to be executed. As you can see, given command runs `midl` executable with corresponded arguments. If you want to know meaning of a specific argument, just read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/midl-command-line-reference).

Comment: Can you please help me with this error C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(2988) : error C2338: 'CAtlExeModuleT' must be used with neither _WINDLL nor _USRDLL defined                                                                                                   I have used remove_definitions(
  -D_WINDLL
) but still getting the same error @Tsyvarev